# countdown timer not reducing hours when minutes and seconds are 0

Tags: javascript, php, timer, setinterval

I have been struggling over this countdown timer for some time. I have made a lot of progress but for some reason when minutes and seconds are 0 it isn't reducing the hours. Why is this?

code:

```
<?php
$timeTo  = strtotime(gmdate("12:24:00")).'<br />';
$timeNow = strtotime('now').'<br />';
$differenceInSeconds = $timeTo - $timeNow;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var s= "<?php Print($differenceInSeconds);?>";
var h= Math.floor(s/3600);
s-= h*3600;
var m= Math.floor(s/60);
s -= m*60;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
    function timer()
    {

    s=s-1;
        if(s == 0 ){
        m=m-1;
        s=59;
          if(s == 0 && m == 0){
          h=h-1;
          s=59;
          m=59;
           if(s == 0 && m == 0 && h == 0){
           // reset the counter
           //return;
           }
          }
        }
//Do code for showing the number of seconds here
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=h+'hrs '+m+'min '+s+'secs ';//(h <= 0 ? ' ' : h+"hr ")+(m <= 0 ? ' ' : m+"min ")+(s < 10 ? '0'+s+'secs ' : s+"secs "); // watch for spelling
                }
        </script>

<span id="timer"></span>
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsP87/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `s == 0` and then decrement it, not in opposite order:

```
s=s-1; // s will be -1
if(s == 0 ){
```

But

```
if (s == 0) {
    // logic here
} else {
    s = s - 1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VsP87/3/

Comment: Thanks Peter, could you suggest how I could add 5 hours when the time is reached?

Comment: Store the original time in a variable that you wouldn't overwrite, and just rebuild `s,m,h` from that if `h == 0`.